# MvvmCross mock view dispatcher doesn't get called

Tags: mvvmcross

I followed the documentation on testing on the MvvmCross website and registered my mock view dispatcher as a singleton.

However, it doesn't get called. I created a very simple ViewModel to demonstrate what happens:

```
public class TestViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public void testShowViewModel()
    {
        ShowViewModel<AnotherViewModel>(); // My mock view dispatcher doesn't get triggered.
        var view_dispatcher = this.ViewDispatcher; // Returns null.
        var mvx_view_dispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>(); // Returns my mock view dispatcher.
    }
}
```

Why isn't my mock dispatcher getting triggered?

Comment: It is unclear how you create your IoC container for your test.

Comment: Exactly as per the instructions at https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/testing/testing.

Comment: Doing nothing fancy other than the absolute minimum described there. So in `AdditionalSetup()`, I register my mock as a singleton.

Comment: Could I get you to file an issue on GitHub with exact reproduction steps so we can look into your issue. That would be much appreciated.